n-manifold embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is bounded by a compact manifold
Suppose $M$ is smooth compact $n$-manifold.
I am trying to prove or disprove:

if $M$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, then it bounds a
compact manifold.

My attempt: if it is embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, its first Stiefel-Whitney class of normal bundle is $w_1(\nu^1)=0$ (11.4 in Milnor). Moreover it bounds compact manifold iff all Stiefel-Whitney numbers are zero (4.10 in Milnor)
I am missing an obvious conclusion or any other piece?
EDIT: Codimension 1 immersions and Stiefel-Whitney classes says that for codimension 1 immersions each Stiefel-Whitney class $w_i(M)$ is equal to the $i$-fold cup product $w_1(M)^i$. So I guess the statement is true.
Additionally, does the same statement hold if $M$ is orientable, namely

If $M$ is orientable and can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, then it bounds a compact manifold.

Then we get zero Euler class of a normal bundle $e(\nu^1)=0$, but additionally all Pontrjagin numbers must vanish.
How would one tackle the statement in codimension 2 embedding setting?

Do you assume $M$ to be compact as well? Othwise take $M = \mathbb R^n$ as a counterexample.

Yes I assume it as well.

“does the same statement hold if $M$ is orientable?” Which statement? That $M$ bounds a compact manifold?

It is a nice exercise to prove that the image of $M$ bounds a compact submanifold with boundary in $R^{n+1}$ (one can do so with elementary tools from Guillemin and Pollack). Orientability is a consequence.
